# Can I cancel a css hover pseudo or force webkit to check for hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

The best current example I have of this problem is here: http://lukes.comyr.com/Tf2MarketThing/index.html

On Safari, when you hover over an item it activates the css hover pseudo, which is a webkit transform:

```
.item:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(30deg);
}
```

However, if you click on the item it moves (via jQuery animate()), but it still remains in the hover animation/state even though the mouse is not over the item, and in order to get rid of the hover pseudo you have to hover over the item again where it has moved.

Is there a way to fix this problem so that the item is in the normal css state after it moves? I was wondering if any of these methods might exist:

- Force browser to recalculate hover boundaries
- Reset or remove the pseudo item class
- Simulate a mouse move event to trigger the hover calculations

Edit: Pathetically, the link seems to be overloaded now so heres a couple of screenshots to help illustrate the problem:

This here is what the item looks like when you hover over it, notice how it's rotated compared to the other elements

[image: Hovering]

This is what the item looks like after it moves, which is still rotated in the hover pseudo, even though the cursor hasn't moved from it's original position (Where the gap is in the upper right corner)

[image: Still hovering]

Comment: remove the class `.item` on hover, and when the animation complets, add the class back.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it didn't work, it remained in the hover state despite not having the class assigned for some reason, and I can't remove the class since it has a separate webkit-animation that plays every time the class is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  not full solution , but just trying to give you idea how to solve it

```
$('.item').click(function(){$(this).css('transform','scale(1)')})
$('.item').hover(function(){$(this).css('transform','scale(1.5)')})
$('.item').mouseout(function(){$(this).css('transform','scale(1)')})
```

Comment: Just setting the transform manually with your last line fixed it for me, it deviously simple compared to what I was expecting haha